# Как заполнить срез с пропусками значений в DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть такой код:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 4],
                   'B': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', np.nan]})
df
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выполняю команду:

```
df[(df['A'].isnull()) & (df['B'] == 'b')].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

И ничего не меняется в исходном `df`.

Подскажите как заменить данные в `df` по условиям: заполнить пустые значения в колонке `А`, если в колонке `В` значение `b`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том что работая со срезом вы работаете с копией данных (подробнее об этом можно прочесть [здесь](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)).

Попробуйте так:

```
In [17]: df.loc[(df['A'].isnull()) & (df['B']=='b'), 'A'] = 0

In [18]: df
Out[18]:
     A    B
0  1.0    a
1  0.0    b
2  0.0    b
3  NaN    c
4  4.0  NaN
```

альтернативный вариант:

```
In [24]: df.update(df.loc[(df['A'].isnull()) & (df['B'] == 'b'), 'A'].fillna(0))

In [25]: df
Out[25]:
     A    B
0  1.0    a
1  0.0    b
2  0.0    b
3  NaN    c
4  4.0  NaN
```

Comment: Значения в B тоже меняются, а нужно только в А

Comment: @Serg4356, пардон, не заметил - сейчас исправил...

Comment: условие df['A'].isnull() излишнее в альтернативном варианте, мне кажется